Neovim displays with different colors, compared to Vim. Why?
I've migrated from Vim to Neovim, including my old .vimrc, and all packages on ~/.vim. This seems to work mostly fine, but, for some reason, colors and syntax are different:


I've tried the set termguicolors! command, as suggested by j`ey on #neovim @ Libera.Chat. The background color seems to match, but the syntax highlight is still messed up. Also, for some reason, I need to explicitly call that command; adding it to init.nvim has no effect. Is it possible to solve these issues?

neovim has a new default colorscheme that is different to vim. Might be it if you don't have colorscheme setup in your configuration.


New default color scheme. It has different (I'd argue, better)
definitions and links of built-in groups. Adding colorscheme vim or
source $VIMRUNTIME/colors/vim.lua restores previous defaults.
Option 'termguicolors' is now enabled by default if terminal emulator
is known to support it. Adding vim.o.termguicolors = false makes it
work like previous default.

https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/1d66jlw/color_scheme_problems_in_0100/
So basically set the colorscheme to what it used to be and disable termguicolors.
